# My SQL Unique Values - Unexpected Result

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table tblSchedule and following are the values in it.

```
INSERT INTO tblSchedule (`scheduleID`, `eventID`, `price`, `eventDate`) VALUES 
(1, 1, 150, '2013-04-20 00:00:00'),
(2, 1, 100, '2013-04-15 00:00:00'),
(3, 2, 80, '2013-04-18 00:00:00'),
(4, 3, 120, '2013-04-26 00:00:00'), 
(5, 3, 140, '2013-04-22 00:00:00'),
(6, 2, 100, '2013-04-22 00:00:00');
```

I want to get the Unique events Ordered by eventDate ASC. 
I have tried the following query but this gives wrong price values and correct eventDates.

```
SELECT MIN(eventDate) as minEventDate, eventId, price
FROM tblSchedule
GROUP BY eventID
ORDER BY minEventDate
```

[Click Here to see code in action](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/494e2/2)

Can anyone tell me what is going on here and the breakdown of the right query?

Comment: For clarification are you looking to get the most **recent** `price` and `eventDate` for each `eventID` or the **oldest**?

Answer (score 3):

First you should find `MIN(EventDate)` for each `eventID` and then find rows from the original table with these `eventID` and `MIN(EventDate)` using JOIN

```
SELECT * FROM tblSchedule
JOIN
 ( SELECT MIN(eventDate) as minEventDate, 
          eventId
        FROM tblSchedule
   GROUP BY eventID
 ) as T on tblSchedule.eventID=t.EventId
           AND
           tblSchedule.eventDate=t.minEventDate

ORDER BY eventDate
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/494e2/6)</kbd>

Comment: Why we have to make such complex SQL query for simpler result?
Shouldn't it automatically sync the date rows with price?

Comment: This is not that complex IMHO. Its actually very simple and clear.

Comment: @MasoodAnwar:  You group by `eventId` and find `MIN(eventDate)` for each `eventID` but WHY do you think `price` will be from THE SAME row where `eventDate` is minimal? As you have learned `price` can be from the different rows. So actually you can think about it as a totally random row selected. Even more such GROUP BY syntax (when you can use `price` field in the SELECT without aggregation) is unallowed in for example MSSQL and Oracle.

Comment: Thanks Valex! It helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT eventDate, eventId, price 
FROM (SELECT eventDate, eventId, price
      FROM tblSchedule
      ORDER BY eventId, eventDate
     ) AS A 
GROUP BY eventId;
```

Check the [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/edd4f/2)

**OUTPUT**

```
|                    EVENTDATE | EVENTID | PRICE |
|------------------------------|---------|-------|
| April, 15 2013 00:00:00+0000 |       1 |   100 |
| April, 18 2013 00:00:00+0000 |       2 |    80 |
| April, 22 2013 00:00:00+0000 |       3 |   140 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use timestamp for this

```
SELECT * FROM `tblschedule` ORDER BY TIMESTAMP( eventDate )
```

OR

```
SELECT DISTINCT(eventID) as event, eventDate FROM `tblschedule` ORDER BY TIMESTAMP( eventDate )
```

Instead of * you can put whatever columns you want to return.

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/93e34/5)